# Laravel routes not updating on server

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-artisan

I have added a Laravel route to the web.php file and everything works fine locally but on deployment, it says that page is not found. The thing is that the newly added routes seem to be in web.php on the server as well but `php artisan route:list` does not display these new routes. Most of the solutions here recommend to run `php artisan route:clear` and then `php artisan route:cache` but there is not any routes.php file in /bootstrap/cache/ directory so that routes were not caching anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont run route:cache 
just clear and it will auto get it cached from your routes

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: I tried `php artisan route: clear` but it did not work. After clearing configuration cache as well, it does